# Accidentally downvoted, noticed after it was already locked in

Tags: support, downvotes

I was reading a question, on my phone, in bed, before going to sleep.

Woke up hours later and checked Stack Overflow on my desktop and was surprised to see that I had cast a downvote which I immediately tried to retract but no longer could because my vote has been locked in. I don't remember pressing the vote, up or down button at all.

I do not want to downvote the answer since there is nothing wrong with it. It is actually correct and I agree with it.

What do I do? Can a moderator intervene and remove the downvote?

Downvoted answer: [how to use localtime_s with a pointer in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258285/how-to-use-localtime-s-with-a-pointer-in-c/35260146#35260146)

Comment: Down-votes usually imply disagreement on meta. Conversely, up-votes usually imply agreement. It doesn't affect your reputation. Don't worry about it--down-votes aren't usually an indicator that something is majorly wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you make a minor edit, that should unlock the post so that you can vote again. Be sure to provide an explanation about why you've made the edit so that the OP understands. And/or edit again after voting to remove the change.

Comment: actually worked. just added a space to the code snippet on the answer. basically a formatting edit.